# High Charts: Change each individual plot/marker size, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to change the size of each plot on the following [chart](http://jsfiddle.net/JtxHv/), is it possible?

I did try to change the line thickness however this made no difference to each individual plot on each line series.

```
series:{ [<%= GraphSeries4 %>],

                marker: {

                enabled: false

            },
                },
```

Graph series is a variable which collects data from an Sql database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `lineWidth` parameter in `series` list. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtxHv/1/) code. Crucial code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    // some other code
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            lineWidth: 5
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5],
            lineWidth: 15
        }
    ]
}
```

Also see [the documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series) for possible parameters.

**//EDIT**

You can also change markers size on whole chart or single points. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtxHv/2/). And the code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    // some other code
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            // marker setting for all points in this series
            marker: {
                radius: 5
            },
            lineWidth: 5
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            // marker setting for second point only
            data: [-0.2, { y: 0.8, marker: { radius: 15 }}, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5],
            lineWidth: 15
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That changes the thickness of the line however does not affect each plot size. Is there a method for changing the plot size?

Comment: What's the plot size? I don't understand the question. :)

Comment: @ freakish I did try the code which i have just put in my original post however didnt seem to work. Each value on the graph is represented by a dot, I'm trying to decrease the size of them

Comment: @user1091114 I've updated the answer. Is this what you want? :) You set `enabled: false` in marker settings. You have no markers at all. Perhaps you reached the minimum of thickness of markers? Or maybe I still don't understand the question. :)